# how to open popup on form submit in php using jquery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, popup

I am trying to open a popup on submit button of a contact form below is the code

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="mail2.php" onsubmit="return valid();">
            <label>Name :</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="contact-input-box" />

            <label>Contact No. :</label>
                <input name="telephone" type="text" id="telephone" class="contact-input-box" />

            <label>Email :</label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="contact-input-box" /><br class="clearBoth" />  

            <label>Gender :</label>
            <span>Mail</span> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
            <span>Femail</span> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> <br class="clearBoth" />

            <label>product :</label>
            <select name="product" class="dropdown" id="product">
                      <option>Product</option>
                      <option value="cd">CD</option>
                      <option value="dvd">DVD</option>
            </select> <br class="clearBoth" />

            <label>Comment :</label>
                <textarea name="comment"  id="comment" class="contact-input-box1"></textarea><br class="clearBoth" />
                <p id="button1"></p>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" title="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" /> 
        </form>
```

but I am unable to open the popup. form is working fine. currently it is went on thankyou.html page. I need to open the thank you message in popup box.

Comment: What kind of popup? A javascript `alert()`, or a new window/tab?

Comment: what does myFunction() do?post code

Comment: I am tried to open a alert with myFunction(); i will remove it..

Comment: yes new window in jquery popup

Comment: I like the `jquery or javascript` in the title.

Comment: You don't want to redirect then you need to make an AJAX call and on success open a lightbox. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715081/jquery-ajax-login-form-submit-on-enter)

Comment: Ok I will try as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a javascript popup, use `alert("message");` in your `myFunction()`.

If you mean a new window/tab, put this in your form `target="_blank"` so it reads like this:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="mail2.php" target="_blank" onsubmit="return valid();">
```

---

Also you're doing 2 separate things when submitting your form:

- Your form has `onsubmit="return valid();"`
- Your `submit`button has `onclick="myFunction();"`

You should put the validation and the contents of the `myFunction()` function in a `submit`-function like this:

```
$("#contact").on("submit", function()
{
    alert("Testmessage");

    // Validation
    // if validation fails:
        return false;

    // Then whatever you do in `myFunction();`
});
```

Comment: on click of submit button it is currently redirecting to the thankyou.html page & i want that page will not redirect to any other page just stay on current page & popup will open on click of submit button.

Comment: But when someone presses the `Enter` key inside a textfield, your submitbutton isn't clicked

Comment: instead you can handle your things in submit function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery ui dialog. For that make a div in your html and put the content inside the div that you want to show in popup.

```
<div id="my-popup-div"> this content will be shown inside popup </div>
```

now use jquery dialog initiator.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        $("#my-popup-div").dialog({});
    })
```

now in your function

```
function myFunction()
{
   $("#my-popup-div").dialog("open");
}
```

for more customization follow ui tutorials [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the JqueryUi Dialog. This way you can show de thankyou.html in a customizable pop up.

It's a easy way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  $('#button').submit(function() {
      alert('Handler for .submit() called.'); //you can call myFunction()  here
      return false  //will stop the form submission.

    });
```

If you don't want to stop the form submission there will be no need to show any alerts,because the page already submitted.

Or you can try `setTimeout` for sometime to show popup of thankyou and then submit the form

Answer (score 0):

If you want a popup to ask the user whether to submit the form or not then you can hook into form onsumbit event:

```
function beforeSubmit() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure, you want to submit form?")) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

[EXAMPLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7584F/2/)