# Any security issue with sending login data with jQuery?

Tags: php, forms, security

A short answer - is there any security issues in sending e-mail + password through ajax to another page? :)

My thought is, that the information could maybe be grabbed in the sending, which may be a flaw compared to doing it "the conventional way" with just a form-action with a "link" to the login-action page.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the same if you send your password with a Form over POST or send an Ajax request over POST. You should use SSL then the requests is enrypted and save.

But you should use a POST request. Don't send your password over GET its not the best way.

[jQuery/AJAX login form submit on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715081/jquery-ajax-login-form-submit-on-enter)

Comment: So what I can read from your answer is, that sending a form by an AJAX form request is just as vulnerable as sending it with a normal POST? :)

Comment: Can you expand on why GET is not the best way? As it stands it just seems like a random unjustified statement

Comment: POST vs GET

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other

With the caveat that for a GET the URL shown in the location bar can expose data that would be hidden in a POST.

Answer (score 2):

You can transfer the password into a *hash* on clientside before it is sent anywhere and then do hash comparison serverside.

But you have the same problem with a Post or Get request ... itis always the same if you don't use SSL, however in the light of the NSA ordeal, even that seems less secure.

**EDIT**
It could makes sense if you convert the password hash clientside and store it in a hidden field and send it off for comparison instead of sending the password. This however poses the threat that hashes could be collected directly client-side Further it would be bad cause you would also need to expose your seeding (which you should be using anyhow) etc. it is a flawed approach.

Use SSL and be done with it.

You could however bloat your request with **http://www.jcryption.org** which is based on jQuery

Comment: This stops the password itself being seen, But you can still login with the hash.

Comment: How is that possible? Unless your code is really badly written, it doesn't make sense

Comment: You cannot login with the HASH!

Answer (score 2):

The "conventional way" that you refer to is *as bad* as POSTing an AJAX request. Sending via HTTPS instead of HTTP gives you *better* security (but sceptics would quickly point out that some encryption schemes used via HTTPS are trival to decode)

Answer (score 1):

**No.**
You need to set up SSL on your server and use an HTTPS connection in order to be saf*er*.